# Populating K2 Smartobjects from AD Attributes

Tags: active-directory, k2, k2-smartforms, k2-smartobjects

I am trying to automatically populate an instance of an AD User smartobject from no input parameters. The way I figure it is that if the smartobject is accessed by a user of the Active Directory, it might be able to harvest from that user certain basic parameters of that user's account.

This might be nonsense, for all I know, so please tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way.

I am trying to construct a method for the AD User object that will recognize and recall the credentials of whomever activates it, but I cannot seem to find any service object that accesses the user account by default.

My real goal here is to ensure a user cannot enter a false name in the smartform I am building. My thoughts are that I might check a user's input against their stored AD credentials. It may be there are easier or more practical ways to go about verifying identity, but whatever the case, I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: The first question I have is how are you planning to use this smart object? The out of the box SmartObject/AD Service doesn't support the scenario you are outlining. IF you are calling the Smart Object from Smart Forms, the Smart Forms app is aware of the user consuming the page and you could then configure a rule to taken the logged on user and pass that ID to the smart object call. The expectation is that the mechanism that is calling the smart object is aware of who the calling user is and there for will be able to pass that detail into the smart object. If you can provide more about your u

Comment: Thanks for the response. A tad late, but I'll keep it in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Context Browser`, under `System Values` under `Current User`, you can get details about the currently authenticated user (unless `Anonymous Access` is enabled). You won't have to get user input at all, or execute an `AD User Smart Object` method, if you are trying to guarantee the user is who they say they are.

To get details about the current user from the `AD User Smart Object`, in the `SmartForm` rule where you execute the `AD User Smart Object`'s `GetuserDetails` method input mappings, you can user the current user's `Name` and other fields from the context browser under `System Values`.  The output parameters will include the user email and display name and other useful details about the user.

[image: Smartforms Rule Example Screenshot]